# Why doesn't free execute munmap?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, strace

I have the following code:

```
     unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)valloc(page_size);
     if (!p) {                 
             ret = -1;
             goto out;
     }
     printf("valloc: allocated %d bytes, virtual address: %p\n", page_size, p);

     memset(p, 0xFF, page_size);
     memcpy(p, s, sizeof(s));

     trace_mem(p, sizeof(s));
     printf("Memory: %p -  press any key\n", p);
     getchar();

     if (ioctl(fd, MY_IOC_PATCH) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ioctl %s error(%d): %s\n ", "MY_IOC_PATCH", errno, strerror(errno));
            ret = -1;
            goto out;
     }

     if (p) {
             printf("free: freed %d bytes, virtual address: %p\n", page_size, p);
             free(p);
     }
      .........................
```

Then I use strace to observe system calls: strace ./my_program I get the following:

```
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1533, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =      0xb7730000
brk(0)                                  = 0x9d81000
brk(0x9da4000)                          = 0x9da4000
fstat64(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb772f000
read(0, "\n", 1024)                     = 1
ioctl(3, RTC_IRQP_SET, 0x1000)          = 0
read(0, "\n", 1024)                     = 1
ioctl(3, RTC_EPOCH_READ, 0x9d82000)     = 0
read(0, "\n", 1024)                     = 1
close(3)                                = 0
valloc: allocated 4096 bytes, virtual address: 0x9d82000
```

After the first IOCTL I don't see munlock. I suppose that free must use munlock to unmap memory, but it doesn't cause. What is the reason for that?

Comment: "I suppose that free must use munlock to unmap memory" – it certainly doesn't **have to;** it's entirely up to the implementation. Most memory managers don't give back `free()`d space to the OS; they keep it reserved instead for fast access some time later.

Comment: `valloc()`? You mean `vmalloc()`?

Comment: valloc() allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory address will be a multiple of the page size.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Paramagnetic Croissant's comment, above, qualifies as "the Answer" to this one.  It is ordinary practice for `malloc()` implementations to ask the operating-system for more memory when they need it, but then to never give it back.  For any operating-system.

You see, there's really no *need* to "give it back."  Pestering the kernel, asking him to carve out more VM-space and to update the memory-management data structures, is a comparatively expensive operation.  But, it doesn't really "cost" much to keep the storage around. (The cost of "releasing them" doesn't gain you anything, *especially* if you turn right around and have to ask for them again!) So, you just do it *once.*

If you stop using those pages, they'll eventually get swapped-out, and the physical resource (page frames) will automagically get used for other purposes.  "No harm, no foul."  But then, if you then suddenly start *using* that storage again, there's no reason to "pester the kernel" a second (or third) time.  The pages just get swapped-in again, and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

malloc/valloc(page size variant of malloc) actually gets the memory addresses from virtual address space. These addresses have mapping to physical address by way of page tables that are specific to a particular process.Thence in my opinion all kernel has to do in case of [vm]alloc is:

1)  Attach an anonymous segment to the process.

2) Associate a bunch of virtual address (heap area) entries with physical pages, of course on first use.

In case of "free" it just needs to disassociate the virtual memory entries with the physical pages. Note that since these are anonymous pages it aint need to care where the "data" needs to go, while mmaping a file it may need to stage it back to the disk.

The physical pages are tracked and managed by the memory manager independently and is governed by cache principles (hot, cold color etc). Thus there is no question of free trying to give back memory to the kernel. Since all it got was a virtual address. It will give back the virtual address to the glibc library which should maintain virtual address chunks for use by the specific process.